# When do we need a bleeder resistor?

Tags: capacitor, current, discharge

In the power supply design that I have, I used a NPN transistor to pull constant ~10mA from the linear regulator:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvFgRg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Before the regulator I have a 4700uF capacitor after the bridge rectifier.

When having a circuit that is pulling some current from the main when the power is off, is using a bleeder resistor in parallel with the capacitor necessary?

Comment: (1) Why do you care? (2) If you do need to care, do you need to care about whether V+ or V- discharges first?

Comment: @Transistor shouldn't I care? in all standard designs there's a bleeder resistor... no it doesn't matter as long as both get discharged.

Comment: Usually we just let the circuit load discharge the power supply unless there is some reason why the load should be switched off promptly.

Comment: @Transistor So with the 10mA current sink and circuit load there's no need for bleeder resistor. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some **regulator** circuits require a standing current for them to actually *regulate* output voltage. You can call this a *bleed* current too. Without this current, output voltage *could rise above what you intend*.
 Most designs expect to always supply current to a load, and can misbehave should reverse-current flow. If a load can dump current *back into* the supply, a more aggressive bleed may be required. This is possible with inductive loads, for example

The common LM317 chip is an example of a regulator requiring a *minimum load current*. Most circuits simply use low-value resistors at the chip's output. The two resistors serve dual purpose:

- the top current-setting resistor provides minimum standing current (bleed current). A value of 270 ohms will pull 4.6+mA out of the LM317 satisfying the **Minimum load current to maintain regulation** spec shown in Texas Instruments LM317 data sheet (below).
- act as output-voltage set. Top resistor sets a current for the bottom resistor. A top-resistor of 270 ohms plus an 820 ohm bottom resistor sets output voltage to nearly +5.0V, as an example.

[image: from Texas Instruments LM317 data sheet]

 Another reason for including a bleed...A user might reasonably expect a variable-output voltage supply to output no voltage when first turned on. A careful person should prevent over-volting their precious circuits by turning down the "variable" control to minimum before switching on.

But this *also assumes* that the supply has been internally bled from the last user, who might have required far more voltage than you. An internal capacitor without a bleed could still be charged to that high-voltage. The regulator circuit is unable to pull that high-voltage down : your unfortunate circuit might do that instead, and die.

Answer (score 1):

It is generally good practice to have a bleeder resistor, especially at voltages which can shock someone. Not only can it prevent a shock, it can prevent accidentally shorting the capacitor to and damaging other components during servicing.

In your case the load will most likely discharge the capacitor every time, but in the event the load gets disconnected its a good back up so why not? Resistors are cheap.